# XHR requests in Google Caja

Tags: google-caja

I'm trying to cajole a web page from an other domain to my host page. I would like this page to communicate with my rest API through AJAX. I have tried to have the rest API on both my host page domain and the domain from where I get the page to cajole. In both scenarios my request seems to be blocked, Firebugs NET tab doesn't show any get request. I have changed the uripolicy to allow the specified domains.

My question is therefore if it is possible to make XHR from a cajoled web page from another domain?

Answer (score 0):

XHR requests made from Caja guest content should be treated as from the origin of the host page (not where the guest content was loaded from). If your URI policy allows the request and the API is on the same domain as the host page, or the API allows cross-origin requests, then it *should* work. If not, find a small test case and file a bug?